# Counting values in pandas dataframe of non-nan values with date comparison condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date_1                  Date_2                  Date_3
2019-12-18 13:43:47                             2019-12-18 13:43:47
2019-12-18 13:43:48     2019-12-18 13:43:47     
2020-12-18 17:51:17
2020-12-18 17:51:17     2020-12-18 17:51:17     2020-12-18 17:51:17
```

I am trying to count the number of values present in each columns if they meet a condition that the date is more than `today`.

My code:

```
today=pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta(days=1)

total_date_1_events = len([df['Date_1']>today])+1
total_date_2_events = len([df['Date_2']>today])+1
total_date_3_events = len([df['Date_3']>today])+1
```

If I print each of my 3 variables they all output the same result which is 4, I understand that is because empty rows are being counted as well.

I would like to get the following results:

```
total_date_1_events = 2 # because there are only 2 dates that are bigger than today
total_date_2_events = 1 # because there are only 1 date that is bigger than today
total_date_3_events = 1 # because there are only 1 date that is bigger than today
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: `len(df['Date_1']>today)` is equal `len(df['Date_1'])` always , you need : `df['Date_1'].gt(today).sum().add(1)`. `df['Date_1']>today` return a Series with True or False ( the same as `df['Date_1'].gt(today)`), but the lenght of the series it's the same...

Comment: Not sure what does `gt` stand for and which package it comes from.

Comment: `gt` is the same as `>` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html

Comment: in another hand you don't need put in list `len(df['Date_1']>today)` is the lenght of the series equal to `len(df)` but `len([df['Date_1']>today])` 
is the length of a list that contains a series in the first element of the list, that is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
sum(df.Date_1>pd.Timestamp.today())
sum(df.Date_1>pd.Timestamp.today())
sum(df.Date_1>pd.Timestamp.today())
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas way [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) and [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df['Date_1'].gt(today).sum()
```

---

if you need it for more column you could do:

```
s = df[['Date_1','Date_2','Date_3']].gt(today).sum()
```

this create a Series. YOu can acces to values using:

```
s['Date_1']
s['Date_2']
```

Comment: I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: sorry only replace `.add(1)` by +1 :)

Comment: In this case we dont need to add 1, because we have the sum already, thank you!

Comment: okey but I think it is better consider  `s = df[['Date_1','Date_2','Date_3']].gt(today).sum()` instead write the same line n times :)

Comment: I think that's a much cleaner solution, and you're using `[ ]` to access columns instead of the attribute style, which I hate!